# What is the role of the slash ("/") in chemical reactions?

Tags: notation

I have always been confused about the role of slash in chemical reactions.

In some reactions, e.g. $\ce{NaBH4}/\ce{OH-}$ it means we use both compounds, right?

And in reactions where we write $\ce{Pt/Pd/Ni}$ do we mean platinum or palladium or nickel?

Comment: Usually in a reaction slash means both. H2, Pd/C is the prime example. If it's in a sentence, i.e. plain text, I'd say it probably means or, although context is important as well.

Comment: I always thought the everyday meaning is implied and it seems to have been a correct assumption every time.

Comment: I'm not aware of the standard, but the textbook usually specifies it above the reaction when it is first mentioned. It would be useful to have convention.

Answer (score 2):

The ambiguity seems to come not so much from Chemistry, but from English punctuation. [Slashes](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/slash.html) are often used in place of "and", "or", or the latin "cum" (meaning combined with). It seems that it unfortunately is just context dependent, though I would argue its use as a replacement for "or" is most consistent grammatically and defining this to be the meaning of the slash would eliminate ambiguity in these situations.

Answer (score 1):

The "/" mainly means the medium in which the compound is present. NaBH4/OH- means NaBH4 is being used in basic medium. After all the medium in which a particular compound is present matters much in a chemical reaction. Similarly, Pt/Pd/Ni (which is commonly used when H2 is a reactant) implies H2 is being passed over any of the above 3 metals (which help to dissociate H2 into [H] atoms to help in reaction).

Comment: The two uses of '/' that you are describing seem to be completely different, not similar.

Comment: Agree with bon...in the first example of yours / plays role of and in 2nd it plays role of or..this is exactly my confusion